# JUNIT Test Cases- Spark JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, junit

I am new to spark with Java programming. I have a method to read data from Oracle database. Now i need help in writing test cases using JUnit Framework for the below code.

Dataset df = spark.read().format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl, dbTable1, connectionProperties);

Answer (score 1):

You can using the below approach, You need to use H2 library which will create
an in memory temporary server with database, in which you can create the required table with
test data. this example is using MS Sql Server (MODE=MSSQLServer), you can change it.

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.200</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Actual Method

```scala
    def GetJDBCDataframe(spark: SparkSession, jdbcUrl: String, connectionProperties :Properties): DataFrame = {
        val employeesQuery = "(SELECT * FROM Employee) ref_alias"
        val df = spark.read.jdbc(url = jdbcUrl, table = employeesQuery, connectionProperties)
        df
    }
```

Testcase method:

```scala
    @Test
    def GetJDBCDataframe(): Unit = {
    
      val spark: SparkSession = {
        SparkSession
          .builder()
          .master("local[2]")
          .appName("SampleSparkScalaTest")
          .getOrCreate()
      }
      //H2 library connection for creating a inmemory MSSQL databse
      val url = "jdbc:h2:mem:Mydatabasename;MODE=MSSQLServer"
    
      val connectionProperties = new Properties()
      connectionProperties.setProperty("user", "sa")
      connectionProperties.setProperty("password", "")
    
      Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")
      val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProperties)
    
      //create mock jdbc Employee table (immemory)
      conn.prepareStatement("create table Employee(EmpId int, FirstName varchar, LastName varchar)").executeUpdate()
      conn.prepareStatement("insert into Employee values (1, 'Brain', 'Lara')").executeUpdate()
      conn.prepareStatement("insert into Employee values (2, 'Virat', 'Kholi')").executeUpdate()
      conn.prepareStatement("insert into Employee values (3, 'MS', 'Dhoni')").executeUpdate()
      conn.commit()
    
      val rowCount = TransactionLogicTransformation.GetJDBCDataframe(spark,url,connectionProperties).count()
    
      assertEquals(3, rowCount)
    }
```

Comment: thank you. although it would still be nice to see a java response